# Could not match expected type in instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am writing a 'simple' example for implementing type classes however I am having a hard time figuring out why this does not compile:

```
class Euclidean a where
  norm :: (Euclidean a, Floating b) => a -> b

data Point a b = Point a b

instance (Floating x, Floating y) => Euclidean (Point x y) where
  norm (Point x y) = x
```

It fails with:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘x’
  ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at src/Simple.hs:10:10
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        norm :: (Euclidean (Point x y), Floating b) => Point x y -> b
      at src/Simple.hs:11:3
Relevant bindings include
  x :: x (bound at src/Simple.hs:11:15)
  norm :: Point x y -> b (bound at src/Simple.hs:11:3)
In the expression: x
In an equation for ‘norm’: norm (Point x y) = x
```

Note: The desired function implementation would be of course
`sqrt $ (x * x) + (y * y)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look carefully at the types referenced in definition of the class:

```
class Euclidean a where
    norm :: (Euclidean a, Floating b) => a -> b
```

The `a` in the second line is bound by the `a` in the first line. But the `b` is not bound by anything, so it is implicitly universally quantified. In other words the above definition is equivalent to

```
class Euclidean a where
    norm :: forall b. (Euclidean a, Floating b) => a -> b
```

So for every `Euclidean` type `a`, `norm` is function that takes an `a` value and returns a `b` value for *any* `Floating b`.

So in the example with `Point`, the dummy definition of `norm` that you provided, always returns of value of type `x` whereas the compiler expects you to provide an implementation that returns values of arbitrary `Floating` types.

So how do you solve this? On solution is to do something like that:

```
instance (Real x, Floating x, Floating y) => Euclidean (Point x y) where
    norm (Point x y) = realToFrac x
```

I've added a `Real x` constraint, so that I can call `realToFrac` on `x` to get an arbitrary floating value. Note that probably it would make more sense to replace your `Floating` constraint with `RealFrac`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Now there is another problem: How can I match the type of `x` to the type of `y` ?
I wrote the implementation as
`norm (Point x y) = realToFrac $ sqrt $ (x * x) + (y * y)`

(adding the Real constraint to both types in the instance header), but now it complains that it cannot match `x` with `y`

Comment: Try something like  `instance (Real x, Floating x) => Euclidean (Point x x) where`

Comment: It complains that it needs distinct type variables there, and to add FlexibleConstraints to permit this

Comment: You could enable the `FlexibleConstraints` language extension but it would be better to change the definition of `Point`: `data Point a = Point a a`. This forces both coordinates to have the same type. The define an instance: `instance (Real x, Floating x) => Euclidean (Point x)`

Comment: Another solution I found: convert with `realToFrac` before applying `(+)`: `norm (Point x y) = sqrt $ realToFrac (x * x) + realToFrac (y * y)`

Comment: But your approach is cleaner, so I will go with that. Thanks!